# How to handle multiple warning message when we are running any linux application through bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am running a application through bash script. when we execute the script, application will start and two different warning message ask for [y/n]? for first warning i want to give "Y" and for another "N" but it should take from script only. I don't want to use any user intervention

for single warning we can handle through `echo 'y' | command`. but how to use for multiple warning handling? Please help

Comment: [`man expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure what you want, but almost for every Linux bash command there are a lot of options. For example if you want to remove a file, Linux will ask you if you really want to do that (if you use this command: **#rm -i file2.txt**, you will get this prompt **rm: remove regular empty file `file2.txt'? y**).

To ignore that prompt you can use following option for rm command -f:
**#rm -f file2.txt** where -f means -force

So try to do **#man**  to see if there is an option to avoid prompt.

Comment: Vasiliy, yes you are correct I can use -force. But for me command is generating multiple warnings/question and want to handle each in script itself without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Pass arguments (Y and N or anything else) to the script call like this...

```
./script.bash Y N
```

These can then be accessed in the script (script.bash) with the $1 and $2 variable names. Also you can use $3 $4 .. $N etc.

For example...Script contents

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
```

will return

```
Y
N
```

Comment: actually what you did "Y" and "N"  you provided while running the script . But I want to give inside the script like my eg.  echo "Y" | command this is for one warning but I want to handle multiple warnings when script will execute the command because command is generating multiple warning

Comment: `yes | command  ` is what you need for yes. I'm not sure about no

Comment: If you show us what commands you need to run, there might be a better way.